# Creating a Nested for Loop to Scan Chess Board

Tags: java, for-loop

Shown here is the class ChessBoard which creates the Multi-D array pieces- representing a chess board (8x8). When a piece is moving I am trying to scan the board to see if the piece will move through any spaces that are occupied (and throw illegalMove exception if so). Attached below is how I started the nested for loop for each chessPiece. 
How do I create a nest for-loop to scan the spots[][] for a space's vacancy or not

```
public class ChessBoard {

private Piece spots[][];

public ChessBoard() {
    spots = new Piece[8][8];    
}

public void placePieceAt(Piece piece, ChessPosition position) 
{
    spot[position.getX()][position.getY()] = piece;
    piece.setPosition(position);
}
public abstract class Piece {

private ChessPlayer owner;
private ChessGame game;
protected ChessPosition position;



protected CPiece(ChessPlayer owner, ChessGame game, ChessPosition init_position) {
    this.owner = owner;
    this.game = game;
    this.position = null;

    game.getBoard().placePieceAt(this, init_position);
}

******here is where I was trying 
public void checkIfPositionOccupied(ChessPosition destination){
    ChessBoard[][] occupiedSpaces = new ChessBoard[8][8];
    for (int i = 0; i <8 ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<8; i++){


        }
    }

}
public void moveTo(ChessPosition destination) 



        throws IllegalMove
{
    // Replace with your code as necessary
    throw new IllegalMove(this, position, destination);
}

public char getMark() {
    return mark;
}
```

}

```
class Rook extends Piece {
public Rook(ChessPlayer owner, ChessGame game, ChessPosition init_position) {
    super(owner, game, init_position);
    if (owner == game.getPlayer1()) {
        mark = 'r';
    } else {
        mark = 'R';
    }
}   

public void moveTo(ChessPosition destination) throws IllegalMove
{
    if((position.getX() == destination.getX() && position.getY() != destination.getY()) || (position.getX() != destination.getX() && position.getY() == destination.getY())){
        setPosition(destination);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalMove(this, position, destination);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: How do I create a nest for-loop to scan the spots[][] for a space's vacancy or not

Comment: You need to reconsider this `if(owner == game.getPlayer1())..` too.

Comment: Why you need `  ChessBoard[][] occupiedSpaces = new ChessBoard[8][8];`
   Shouldn't it be ChessPiece[][] occupiedSpaces=ChessPiece[8][8]`??

Comment: I really wouldn't throw an exception for an illegal chess move, it's unnecessarily expensive considering I imagine you'll be handling it in every case. What's wrong with a good old `boolean`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are asking this, but well:

```
 ChessBoard[][] occupiedSpaces = new ChessBoard[8][8];
     for (int i = 0; i <8 ; i++){
     for(int j = 0; j<8; i++){
     if (spot[i][j]!=null)   
          //okay, occupied. 
         {
           // Make whatever you want here.
         }
     }
   }
```

Make a hasPiece() method that returns a boolean if the position is occupied.

Comment: `occupiedSpaces` doesn't have any data yet. `spots[i][j] == null` instead?

Comment: Yeah, my bad!!! Need some more coffee..

It could also be == null, yeah. More simple. ;)

Comment: so then if (spot[i][j] = null)?

Comment: if spot[i][j]!=null  --> means that position has a piece. Then you make whatever you want inside the if {}

Comment: also, don't forget deleting the spot[i][j] value next time the piece moves. If not, spot[i][j]!=null will return TRUE for each position that each piece has moved before.

Answer (score 1):

Something totally wrong..

If `Piece` is something like `Rook` See your relationship `Rook is Piece`. then how does your `ChessBoard` has `64 (8*8)` `Piece`? you Should have seperate class for `Spots` and not to use `Piece` to define `ChessSPots`

Also As per your question `can the board to see if the piece will move through any spaces`

You need not only scan `DestinationPosition` but also scan possible ways to that position for current `Piece`. hence The `Move` method should be Specific to `ConCrete Piece like Rook`

You wont need loop for your `checkIfPositionOccupied` method.

```
public void checkIfPositionOccupied(ChessPosition destination){
    if(spot[destination.getX()][destination.getY()] !=null){
      /*Destination is Occupied*/
    }else{
      /*Destination is Not Occupied*/
    }

}
```